# Problem while Joining using auto-incremented identity column's value in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have to insert some records into two tables.
***prd_StudyMaterialContentMaster*** and **prd_StudyMaterialContentdetails**)

```
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| LID | SID | CID | LType | LTitle | LPrice |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 1   | 1   | 1   | Free  | PDF01  | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 2   | 1   | 1   | Free  | PDF01  | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 3   | 1   | 1   | Free  | VID01  | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 4   | 1   | 1   | Free  | VID01  | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 5   | 1   | 1   | Free  | TEXT01 | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 6   | 1   | 1   | Free  | TEXT01 | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+


+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| autoid | LID | FilePath                                                                       | FType       | SID |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| 1      | 1   | D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296690119774812_RN01.pdf | application | 1   |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
```

Now I am passing this datatable as table valued parameter ,

[image]

Now , after Inserting I am getting output like this,

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.prd_StudyMaterialContentMaster
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| LID | SID | CID | LType | LTitle | LPrice |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 1   | 1   | 1   | Free  | PDF01  | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 2   | 1   | 1   | Free  | PDF01  | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
| 3   | 1   | 1   | Free  | VID01  | 0      |
+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.prd_StudyMaterialContentDetails 
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| autoid | LID | FilePath                                                                       | FType       | SID |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| 1      | 1   | D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296701521836972_RN01.pdf | application | 1   |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| 2      | 3   | D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296701521846973_RN02.pdf | application | 1   |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| 3      | 1   | D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296702021155532_RN04.mp4 | video       | 1   |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
```

as you could see on second table , I am getting invalid LIDs

**expected output would be:**

```
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| autoid | LID | FilePath                                                                       | FType       | SID |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| 1      | 1   | D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296701521836972_RN01.pdf | application | 1   |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| 2      | 2   | D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296701521846973_RN02.pdf | application | 1   |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
| 3      | 3   | D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296702021155532_RN04.mp4 | video       | 1   |
+--------+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
```

My procedure looks like this,

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_InsertUpdateStudyMaterialContentMaster]
@Flag int = null,
@dtLesson dtLesson READONLY,
@sectionName NVARCHAR(30) = NULL,
@courseid NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
@price NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
@Error nvarchar(500) output
AS
BEGIN
    begin transaction t1
        Begin Try
            if @Flag = 1
            BEGIN
            DECLARE @lessionId BIGINT
            
            DECLARE @insertedLessonId TABLE(
                LessionID INT,
                sectionId int
            )

            INSERT INTO dbo.prd_StudyMaterialContentMaster(SID,CID, LType, LTitle, LPrice )
            OUTPUT Inserted.LID,Inserted.SID INTO @insertedLessonId
            SELECT Sid,cid,LType,LTitle,LPrice FROM @dtLesson
            

            INSERT INTO dbo.prd_StudyMaterialContentdetails(FilePath, FType,SID )
            SELECT FilePath,FType,Sid FROM @dtLesson
            

            UPDATE prd_StudyMaterialContentdetails
            SET LID = t.LessionID
            FROM prd_StudyMaterialContentdetails c
                right JOIN @insertedLessonId t
                    ON c.SID = t.sectionId
            WHERE c.LID IS NULL
                set @Error = 'success'  
            END

            else
            begin
                set @Error = '@Flag = '+convert(varchar,@Flag)+' does not match any criteria'
            end                 
        End Try

        Begin Catch
            set @Error = Error_Message()
                rollback transaction t1
                return
        End Catch
    commit transaction t1
END
```

I am also providing you , tvp's structure..

Help needed :) Thanks

[image]

Comment: How would you expect `FROM prd_StudyMaterialContentdetails c right JOIN @insertedLessonId t ON c.SID = t.sectionId` to work when all `SID` and `SectionID` values are `1` in all rows?

Comment: Much appreciated sir, then what should be my joining condition? @AlwaysLearning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a unique column in the @dtLesson parameter so that you can correlate the rows you're spreading across multiple tables. Given your example data `LID` seems like the logical choice.

A limitation of SQL Server is that the `INSERT ... OUTPUT INTO` syntax can only capture columns that were inserted into the target table. This makes it difficult to correlate data when inserting multiple rows into multiple tables.

An alternative is to make use of `MERGE ... OUTPUT INTO` syntax which can capture columns from both the target and source data sets, e.g.:

```sql
create procedure [dbo].[usp_InsertUpdateStudyMaterialContentMaster]
    @Flag int = null,
    @dtLesson dtLesson readonly,
    @Error nvarchar(500) output
as
begin
    begin transaction t1;
    begin try
            if (@Flag = 1)
            begin
                declare @insertedLessons table (
                    InsertedLID int,
                    OriginalLID int
                );

                merge into dbo.prd_StudyMaterialContentMaster as Target
                using @dtLesson as Source
                on (0 = 1) -- this forces the "when not matched" branch
                when not matched then
                    insert (SID,CID, LType, LTitle, LPrice )
                    values (Source.SID, Source.CID, Source.LType, Source.LTitle, Source.LPrice)
                output inserted.LID, Source.LID into @insertedLessons;

                insert dbo.prd_StudyMaterialContentdetails (LID, FilePath, FType, SID)
                select InsertedLID, FilePath, FType, SID
                from @dtLesson Original
                join @insertedLessons Inserted on OriginalLID = LID;

                set @Error = N'success';
            end
            else
                begin
                    set @Error = N'@Flag = ' + convert(varchar(10), @Flag) + N' does not match any criteria';
                end                 
        end try
        begin catch
            set @Error = Error_Message();
            rollback transaction t1;
            return;
        end catch
    commit transaction t1;
end
```

And then to invoke it...

```sql
declare @Error nvarchar(500), @dtLesson dtLesson;
insert @dtLesson values
  (1, 1, 1, 'Free', 'PDF01', 0, 'D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296701521836972_RN01.pdf', 'application', 1),
  (2, 1, 1, 'Free', 'PDF01', 0, 'D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296701521846973_RN02.pdf', 'application', 1),
  (3, 1, 1, 'Free', 'VID01', 0, 'D:\project\EiLMS-1\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\EiLMS\Lessons\637296702021155532_RN04.mp4', 'video', 1);

exec [dbo].[usp_InsertUpdateStudyMaterialContentMaster]
  @Flag = 1,
  @dtLesson = @dtLesson,
  @Error = @Error output;

select @Error as 'Error';
select * from prd_StudyMaterialContentMaster;
select * from prd_StudyMaterialContentdetails;
```

Which yields...

```
Error
-------
success

LID SID CID LType   LTitle  LPrice
--- --- --- ------- ------- ------
1   1   1   Free    PDF01   0
2   1   1   Free    PDF01   0
3   1   1   Free    VID01   0

autoid LID FilePath                                   FType   SID
------ --- ------------------------------------------ ------- ---
1      1   D:\project\...\637296701521836972_RN01.pdf application 1
2      2   D:\project\...\637296701521846973_RN02.pdf application 1
3      3   D:\project\...\637296702021155532_RN04.mp4 video       1
```

Comment: A huge thanks for your effort sir, let me try it and I will reach you for sure if any help needed :) Thanks again :) @AlwaysLearning

Comment: sir I face trouble on sql conecpts, could you please provide my any resources?@AlwaysLearning

Comment: The [Transact-SQL Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) site is very useful as a syntax reference, with examples, but I find it awful to search. To solve the search problem I tend to use either DuckDuckGo or Google with site-specific phrased queries, e.g. ["sql server" "merge" site:learn.microsoft.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22sql+server%22+%22merge%22+site%3Alearn.microsoft.com)